# Can anybody explain how the AudioSessionSetActive(true/false) function works in the iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone

Activating audio session  interrupt audio sessions belonging to built-in applications running in the background, depending on categories and priorities. Deactivating  audio session allows other, interrupted audio sessions to resume. 
               activating audio session ( AudioSessionSetActive(true) ) was working properly,but deactivating audio session ( AudioSessionSetActive(false) ) was not working. can any body suggest me how to deactivate audio session and resume the interrupted audio.

Answer (score 1):

This now dated [blog entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20090602051705/http://benbritten.com/blog/2009/02/02/restarting-openal-after-application-interruption-on-the-iphone/comment-page-1/) explained it well.

Just substitute "OpenAL" with "Your Audio System".

Comment: The link to the blog entry no longer points to a particular post.

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `AudioSessionSetActive(false)`

You should use the following

```
AudioSessionSetActiveWithFlags(false, kAudioSessionSetActiveFlag_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation);
```

to notify other applications to resume their playback.

To understand AudioSession, visit [Apple dev](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW2)